# Rails Link to a Class or iterate an Id

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've got a part of my app displaying messages. I'm trying to use a light box to display part of each message when it is clicked. My problem is that I'm using a ID to link to the hidden div. Since I'm using an ID the link will only bring up the first message instead of each subsequent message. How can I change this so each iterated message will bring up it's own message instead of the first one?

I've included my code below. I'm using the fancybox light box.

Thanks for the help.

```
<tbody>
    <% @messages.each do |m| %>
    <tr>

        <td><%= m.from.name %></td>
        <td><%= truncate(m.topic, length: 30) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to truncate(m.body, length: 35), "#user_message", class: 'fancybox'  %></td>
        <td>
        <%= link_to 'Mark Read', '#', confirm: 'Are you sure?', :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
        <%= link_to 'Reply', '#', confirm: 'Are you sure?', :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-inverse' %>
        <%= link_to 'Delete', '#', confirm: 'Are you sure?', :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <div style="display:none" id="user_message">
        <%= m.body %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution would be to force the IDs to be unique by appending something unique, something like say the message's numeric ID:

```
<% @messages.each do |m| %>
  <tr>
    ...
    <td><%= link_to truncate(m.body, length: 35), "#user_message-#{m.id}", class: 'fancybox'  %></td>
    ...
  </tr>
  <div style="display: none" id="user_message-<%= m.id %>">
  ...
```

Comment: So this almost works... the link is displaying "user_message-8" and so on, but the hidden div is only displaying the id as "user_message-{m.id}" instead of "user_message-8"

Comment: @DaveG: Sorry, wrong interpolation style for the `<div>`, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Its little hard to tell you an exact answer without looking at your JQuery code, But normally the way doing these kind of things are append a dynamic value to distinguish the divs

Ex:

```
<tbody>
    <% @messages.each do |m| %>
    <tr>

        <td><%= m.from.name %></td>
        <td><%= truncate(m.topic, length: 30) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to truncate(m.body, length: 35), "#user_message{m.id}", class: 'fancybox'  %></td>
        <td>
        <%= link_to 'Mark Read', '#', confirm: 'Are you sure?', :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
        <%= link_to 'Reply', '#', confirm: 'Are you sure?', :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-inverse' %>
        <%= link_to 'Delete', '#', confirm: 'Are you sure?', :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <div style="display:none" id="user_message{m.id}">
        <%= m.body %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

note the appender `{m.id}` part

HTH